# How to enter a directory to list all the subdirectories present?

Tags: python, keras

I am stuck with an error. The "Keras_merged_train" directory has two subdirectories named Deepfake and Real. I want to use the glob function to count the length of the folders inside the "Keras_merged_train" directory (the answer should be 2). I figured after printing that the glob isn't entering the directory and just printing the name of the directory. How to fix this?

[image]

This is what I tried. The length should come 2 but it isn't reading the files inside.

[image]

The files inside.

Comment: Please don't post [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2081835) that can be pasted.

Answer (score 1):

`glob` does not enter in the directory by default, you have to append `/*`:

```
keras_merged_train_folders = glob('/content/Keras_merged_train/*')
```

You can also use `pathlib`:

```
import pathlib

data_dir = pathlib.Path('/content/Keras_merged_train')

keras_merged_train_folders = [str(p) for p in data_dir.iterdir() if p.is_dir()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os` to get the names of the files and folders present in a directory and then count them. Here's an example:

```
import os
files = os.listdir('/path/to/directory/')
num_files = len(files)
```

You can read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) for more info about this library.